# Copy Flow Document

Tags: wpf, printing, flowdocument

I'm trying to print flow document with an image.

I use costum paginator which copy the original and modified the copy.

I have not figured a way to copy the document completely.

if i copy on this way, i lose the inlineContainer elements (like images):

```
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        TextRange sourceDocument = new TextRange(document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd);
        sourceDocument.Save(stream, DataFormats.Xaml);
        FlowDocument copy = new FlowDocument();
        TextRange copyDocumentRange = new TextRange(copy.ContentStart, copy.ContentEnd);
        copyDocumentRange.Load(stream, DataFormats.Xaml);
```

if i copy on this way, i lose the text style:

```
   FlowDocument copy = XamlReader.Parse(XamlWriter.Save(document)) as FlowDocument;
```

How can i copy the document with its styles, and all content?

thanks;

Harry.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to copy FlowDocument properly, but for the inlineContainer, I think you can use the preserveTextElements bool parameter (sourceDocument.Save(stream, DataFormats.Xaml, TRUE);